# HttpConnection failing on .connect() for image URL

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve tweet information from a search query into my android application. I'm able to put the username and subject in the listview, but I have trouble grabbing the photo. Here is my GetView method from my adapter

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        UserRecord user = users.get(position);
        if (user != null) {
            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
            TextView subject = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            // Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(user.imageURL);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            if (username != null) {
                username.setText(user.username);
            }

            if(subject != null) {
                subject.setText(user.subject);
            }

            if (img != null){
                try {
                    URL myURL = new URL(user.imageURL);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
```

I traced through my code and it fails on conn.connect() and jumps to the catch statement. Does anyone know why this is happening? I have internet connection enabled in my mainfest. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will jump catch statement, and it will give you follwing Exceptions, 1.`NetworkOnMainThreadException`

2.`NullPointerException`

First one is because you are trying to perform network operation on UI Thread.

Second one is because  your input stream is null, when you are trying to access it, you will get the NullPointerException.

**What you need to do?**

Use Separate `thread` or `AsyncTask` to download images

**is it the best way?**

You need to cache images when you showing images from url in listview, so try to use `UniversalImageDownloader` or `LazyLoadList` to populate images

Answer (score 0):

what is exception that is thrown and the error message?

Regards,
Hugo Pedrosa